# De facto structure or template for spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I have started learning spring framework and I could get my way around it by referencing several example and templates.

But still I'm clueless how to start a spring mvc project from scratch. How would be the structure like ? If I were to choose XML based configuration or Annotation based configuration.

Any reference or suggestion would be helpful.

EDIT:

I'm using maven and trying to deploy with jetty. It would have been nice if archetype generate had a template for spring mvc.

There are some spring plugins available to generate project but still its a bit confusing because it varies between IDE.

**NOTE:**

spring-boot sort of frameworks are simpler. But I'm interested just plain old spring.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: which IDE are you using? If it's Eclipse then there's the Spring Tool Suite which will generate a basic Spring app for you which you can use to study the directory layout, basic configuration files etc to easily get an idea of the first steps.  There's no shortage of tutorials after that to build on from there.

Comment: @FluffmeisterGeneral I'm using IntelliJ but having some hard time deploying with jetty. Tried eclipse as well but thats what confused me as they are slightly different(project structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and run [this example showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase) of mvc features.

Run this in command line

```
$ cd spring-mvc-showcase
$ mvn tomcat7:run
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this Spring`s  [Getting Started guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Comment: Also  if you don`t want to go the spring-boot way, just start with a simple web-archetype and add spring dependencies that your project requires